# Back button is not available when teversing application page from side navigation menu in ionic 2

Tags: ionic-framework, navigation-drawer, back-button, android-side-navigation

I am developing an ionic 2 mobile application, i found when i visit a page through side navigation panel it does not providing the auto generated back button on the particular page, while when i am going to the page in normal traversing form one page by one then that page is available with back button. How could i get the back button from the side navigation panel menu, Please suggest.

```html
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar color="primary">
  <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>dashboard</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
```

Comment: Show code please.

Comment: How does your ts code look for navigating with the 'side navigation panel'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have created sidemenu app while creating a project you can see the below code in **app.component.ts**

```
constructor(public platform: Platform, public statusBar: StatusBar, public splashScreen: SplashScreen) {
    this.initializeApp();

    // used for an example of ngFor and navigation
    this.pages = [
      { title: 'Home', component: Createpage}
    ];

  }

  initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      this.statusBar.styleDefault();
      this.splashScreen.hide();
    });
  }

  openPage(page) {
    // Reset the content nav to have just this page
    this.nav.setRoot(page.component);
  }
```

as you can see in the openPage function it sets the page component as root, hence you cannot see back button, instead you see the hamburger icon, which open sidemenu

**NOW**

if you still wish you to open the page from sidemenu with back button here is what you can do

```
openPage(page) {
    // Reset the content nav to have just this page
    // we wouldn't want the back button to show in this scenario
    if(page.component == HomePage){
      this.nav.setRoot(HomePage);
    } else {
      this.nav.push(page.component);
    }
  }
```

in the above code you check if its the backbutton component ( which you wished to open with back button), if it's true you can set it **push** instead of **setRoot**

comment for more clarification